# Creating irremovable files in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions

What is the chmod setting to make files removable only by the root user? Does there exist a chmod setting that would prevent the root user from removing the file without altering its permissions again/

Comment: `chmod 000 filename`?

Comment: Define "irremovable".  You can do things with `chmod`, but of course the root user can always change the permissions back again.

Comment: @MattBall the only problem with your suggestion is that the file will not be accessible as well :)

Comment: You want a WORM (Write Once Read Many) drive.  You can as a regular user create files that can not be deleted (or even modified) by root.  It is useful for logging.  Even if the root account is hacked, your logs will be safe.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is on hold while questions such as "How to create a file with a given size in Linux" are not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be only removable by the root user

`chown root:root`

`sudo chmod 0644`

You cant make something un-deletable by root

you can help this by

`chattr +i file`

which will need a `chattr -i file` before you can delete